# How do I combine elements from two loops without issues?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I execute this code...

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("games.html", "r") as page:
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

titles = doc.select("a.title")
prices = doc.select("span.price-inner")

for game_soup in doc.find_all("div", {"class": "game-options-wrapper"}):
    game_ids = (game_soup.button.get("data-game-id"))

for title, price_official, price_lowest in zip(titles, prices[::2], prices[1::2]):
    print(title.text + ',' + str(price_official.text.replace('$', '').replace('~', '')) + ',' + str(
        price_lowest.text.replace('$', '').replace('~', '')))
```

The output is...

```py
153356
80011
130187
119003
73502
156474
96592
154207
155123
152790
165013
110837
Call of Duty: Modern Warfare II (2022),69.99,77.05
Red Dead Redemption 2,14.85,13.79
God of War,28.12,22.03
ELDEN RING,50.36,48.10
Cyberpunk 2077,29.99,28.63
EA SPORTS FIFA 23,41.99,39.04
Warhammer 40,000: Darktide,39.99,45.86
Marvels Spider-Man Remastered,30.71,27.07
Persona 5 Royal,37.79,43.32
The Callisto Protocol,59.99,69.41
Need for Speed Unbound,69.99,42.29
Days Gone,15.00,9.01
```

But I'm trying to get the value next to the other ones on the same line

Expected output:

```py
Call of Duty: Modern Warfare II (2022),69.99,77.05,153356
Red Dead Redemption 2,14.85,13.79,80011
...
```

Even when adding `game_ids` to `print()`, it spams the same game id for each line.

How can I go about resolving this issue?

HTML file: https://jsfiddle.net/m3hqy54x/

Comment: loop over all elements in the doc and use an "if..elif..." block to figure out whether you should be updating `game_id` or `title`.  But you're probably not going to end up with a single loop so much as various conditionals and nested loops.  Maybe a few variables as well, depending on what you're trying to scrape.

Comment: I need to run them together, not one or the other

Comment: is `110837\nCall of Duty: Modern Warfare II (2022)` from one title?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like all 3 details (title, price_official, price_lowest) are probably all in a shared container. It would be better to loop through these containers and select the details as sets from each container to make sure the wight prices and titles are being paired up, but I can't tell you how to do that without seeing at least a snippet from (or all of) "games.html"....

---

Anyway, assuming that `'110837\nCall of Duty: Modern Warfare II (2022)'` is from the first title here, you can rewrite your last loop as something like:

```py
for z in zip(titles, prices[::2], prices[1::2]):
    z, lw = list(z), ''
    for i in len(z):
        if i == 0: # title
            z[0] = ' '.join(w for w in z[0].text.split('\n', 1)[-1] if w)
            if '\n' in z[0].text: lw = z[0].text.split('\n', 1)[0]
            continue
        z[i] = z[i].text.replace('$', '').replace('~', '')
    print(','.join(z+[lw]))
```

---

**Added EDIT:** After seeing the html, this is my suggested solution:

```py
for g in doc.select('div[data-container-game-id]'):
    gameId = g.get('data-container-game-id')
    title = g.select_one('a.title')
    if title: title = ' '.join(w for w in title.text.split() if w)

    price_official = g.select_one('.price-wrap > div:first-child span.price')
    price_lowest = g.select_one('.price-wrap > div:first-child+div span.price')
    if price_official: 
        price_official = price_official.text.replace('$', '').replace('~', '')
    if price_lowest: 
        price_lowest = price_lowest.text.replace('$', '').replace('~', '')
    
    print(', '.join([title, price_official, price_lowest, gameId]))
```

prints

```
Call of Duty: Modern Warfare II (2022), 69.99, 77.05, 153356
Red Dead Redemption 2, 14.85, 13.79, 80011
God of War, 28.12, 22.03, 130187
ELDEN RING, 50.36, 48.10, 119003
Cyberpunk 2077, 29.99, 28.63, 73502
EA SPORTS FIFA 23, 41.99, 39.04, 156474
Warhammer 40,000: Darktide, 39.99, 45.86, 96592
Marvel's Spider-Man Remastered, 30.71, 27.07, 154207
Persona 5 Royal, 37.79, 43.32, 155123
The Callisto Protocol, 59.99, 69.41, 152790
Need for Speed Unbound, 69.99, 42.29, 165013
Days Gone, 15.00, 9.01, 110837
```

<sub>Btw, this might look ok for just four values, but if you have a large amount of details that you want to extract, you might want to consider using [a function like this](https://pastebin.com/BpjZSQPi).</sub>

Comment: The HTML file is... https://jsfiddle.net/m3hqy54x/

Comment: @Magicskid I see now. I've added an edit. Hope it helps